# How do I do a clean install of Yeoman?

Tags: yeoman, deprecated, yeoman-generator, yo

I'm trying to do a clean install of Yeoman, but the Yo command persists after I tried the following commands to remove it:

```
sudo npm remove -g yeoman
npm remove -g yeoman
sudo npm remove -g yo
npm remove -g yo
brew uninstall yeoman
brew uninstall yo
sudo brew uninstall yo
sudo brew uninstall yeoman
```

Then when I do a `Yo` or `Yo doctor`, yeoman says:

`Allo Herald! What would you like to do? --> Get me out of here!`

What am I missing here?

Some generators are deprecated, some not working so a reinstall is in order I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my educated guess, you have (or had) multiples versions of `npm` installed. These versions installed packages in different global directories, so `yo` is installed in a folder that newer versions on npm you're installing don't know about.

Anyway, best thing to do is check where the yo binary is with `which yo`. Then delete it, and maybe nuke the folder if there's a bunch of older npm packages in there.

Comment: great thank you - yes I've had a few versions installed. Yo is in my `/usr/local/bin/` folder with a ton of older and new stuff...

Comment: Ok, so to clarify: The issue was with npm - the different versions I had, not with yeoman. But somehow when I removed Yo and reinstalled it, the generators installed from the older npm was still listed. So in the end I just removed them manually.